# Edit a row value in datatable in spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, rscript

How do we edit a row in a datatable in spotfire?
Can we do it using ironpython or R script?

I have a requirement where I want to edit the values in spotfire datatable to see the effect in the respective visuals. The data table is populated using an information link (from a SQL database).

Comment: The easiest way would be to create calculated columns. If you need a permanent solution, then transformation would be the key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Calculated columns would not help. As I need to ass update functionality for the datatables. i.e. A user should be able to edit a value in a row which gets saved in the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.

1. 1-> Create function or packaged function which returns ref-cursor.
      1.1-> In that update your value in table based on where clause. 2-> Once you have function ready, create informationlink on that
   object    using parameter type single. 3-> Once you do that import
   information    link to spotfire using on demand values. 4-> create
   document property    and use that do property as parameter for on
   demand. 5-> keep    datatable refresh manually(uncheck Auto
   Refresh). 6-> provide user    text box to have new values. 7->
   provide 1 button and use    datatable.Refresh(). 8-> it will pass
   your doproperty value to    database and your function will return
   ref-cursor, in that you can    return the sql%rowcount or success or
   failure msg.